# cant do case insensitive search in elastic search

Tags: python, python-3.x, elasticsearch

I'm new to elastic search and trying to do this query right.
So I'm having a document like this:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Văn Hiến"
}
```

I want to get that document in 3 cases:
1/ User input is:  "v" or "h" or "i",...
2/ User input is: "Văn" or "văn" or "hiến",...
3/ User input is: "va" or "van" or "van hi",...

I'm currently can search for case 1 and 2, but not case 3, where the user input don't have the 'tonal' of the Vietnamese language
This is my query, I'm using Python:

```
query = {
                "bool": {
                    "should": [
                        {
                            "match": { 
                                "name": name.lower()
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "wildcard": {
                                "name": {
                                    "value": f"*{name.lower()}*"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
```

Can anyone help me with this? Any helps will be apperciated

Comment: could you please share your mapping properties?

Comment: @karthickS yes sure, this is the mapping of the 'name' field

Comment: ```
"name": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                }
            }
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [lowercase_filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-lowercase-tokenfilter.html) and [mapping_character_filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-mapping-charfilter.html) functions in your mapping.

the following mapping and query will work for all the three usecases you mentioned

Mapping Example:

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "my_tokenizer",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
          ],
          "char_filter": [
            "my_mappings_char_filter"
          ]
        }
      },
      "char_filter": {
        "my_mappings_char_filter": {
          "type": "mapping",
          "mappings": [
            "ă => a",
            "ế => e"
          ]
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "my_tokenizer": {
          "type": "ngram",
          "min_gram": 1,
          "max_gram": 10,
          "token_chars": [
            "letter"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "max_ngram_diff" : "9"
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "my_analyzer",
        "fields": {
          "facet": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Example Query:

```
{
    "query" : {
        "query_string" :{
            "query":"van hi",
             "type": "best_fields",
             "default_field": "name"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't you use the ASCII folding token filter instead of the mapping character filter? The mapping would need at least 67 pairs (assuming lowercase only). Would seem to be easier to fold them.